# Redirect to the page you were before login

Tags: php

I have a page where if you are logged in, you see your username and avatar. If you are not logged in, then you see a connect button that will redirect you to another page where you can enter your username and your password to log in.
What I want to do is after you log in and are redirected on the page you were before logging in.

```
 <?php
session_start();

if (isset($_POST["logIn"])) 
{
              .....

header("Location:../index.php");
 } else
 {  ...}
```

What should I change to header?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1- on login page, you need to get referrer url (from where it was redirected to login page that user not logged in)

2- In that login form, make hidden field with that referrer value like:

```
<input type="hidden" name="redirect" value="<?php echo $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];?>">
```

3- On submit, and verified username and password from database, redirect to this URL like

```
header('location: '.$_POST['redirect']);
```

Comment: Worth mentioning he should make sure that `$_POST['redirect']` url's domain is the same as the website's

Answer (score 1):

You mean you just need to redirect to the referer url ?
If so, try this :

```
header('Location: ' . $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
```

Comment: No , i want to redirect to the page you were before the page of log in